# Redirect URL for client and Rewrite for server with mod_rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting

I have the following problem which has been solved dozens of times, but I don't find any solution.

I am writing a blog engine want to have pretty URLs, so I am using Apache `mod_rewrite` in a `.htaccess` for that. Things like `/page/3 => /?s=3` are working perfectly fine as I can write the pretty URLs in the PHP script. But I have a form field for a search using `method="get"` to submit, so I have no option other than pointing the client to ugly URLs. So what I want is kind of a `Redirect` the client and then `Rewrite` the URL for the server: `/?q=foo =client=> /search/foo =server=> /?q=foo`. (Also `/?q=foo&s=2` => `/search/2/foo`)

Somehow my rules don't work, I hope you can help me out.

```
RewriteRule ^(index\.php)?\?q=(.*)$ search/$2 [R,L]
RewriteRule ^(index\.php)?\?q=(.*)&s=(.*)$ search/$3/$2 [R,L]

RewriteRule ^search/(\d+)/(.*)/?$ index.php?q=$2&s=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^search/([^/]*)/?$ index.php?q=$1 [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to only redirect when the actual request is for the ugly URL, you can't match against the URI because it will loop: ugly URL is requested, redirect to friendly URL, friendly URL is requested, rewritten to ugly URI internally, redirected to friendly URL, etc etc

So try this instead of your fry two rules:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /(index.php)?\?q=([^&]+)&s=([^\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^ /search/%3/%2/? [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /(index.php)?\?q=([^\ &]+)
RewriteRule ^ /search/%2/? [L,R=301]
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but this doesn't do it for me, I'm getting a 500 now :( My `error.log` tells me: `[Sat Aug 18 05:18:42 2012] [alert] [client 127.0.0.1] .../.htaccess: RewriteCond: cannot compile regular expression '^[A-Z]{3,9}\\ /(index.php)?\\?q=([^\\ &]+)\\', referer: http://localhost/.../?q=foo` I even tried modifications fo your code, but nothing did work.

Comment: @Ps0ke Sorry, there was a type in the second rewrite condition, there's a stray `\` at the end there, I've edited the answer

Comment: It still doesn't work. There is no error anymore, but it still doesn't redirect. What's the first string in the `RewriteCond` (`^[A-Z]{3,9}\`) and why is the regex in the `RewriteRule` just a `^`-Start-Of-Line marker?

Comment: @ps0ke because `%{THE _REQUEST}` looks something like this: `GET /?q=something HTTP/1.1` and its matching againt the reqiest method (the GET). The second thing os because we don't care what the uri is, we just matched against it in the condition.

Comment: Shouldn't we then use %{REQUEST_URI} then? "**`REQUEST_URI`** *The path component of the requested URI, such as `/index.html`. This notably excludes the query string which is available as as its own variable named `QUERY_STRING`.*"

Comment: @ps0ke no, because the rewrite engine loops, and each iteration the %{REQUEST_URI} variable changes. You need tonmatch against the request itself.